# How can I disable the screensaver and lock screen in Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, desktop

It's very disturbing when making a Kiosk application, every time the lock screen and screensaver shows up, also many popup + battery or updates shows up.

Where and how can I completely disable the lock screen, screen saver and alerts via a configuration file or from the terminal?

I have the tried following but nothing works:

1. failed

   ```
   vim /etc/default/acpi-support
   ;LOCK_SCREEN=true
   ```
2. failed

   ```
   $ gconftool-2 --type boolean -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/lock/suspend false
   $ gconftool-2 --type boolean -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/lock/blank_screen false
   $ gconftool-2 --type boolean -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/lock/hibernate false
   $ sudo init 6
   ```
3. failed (but worked for disabling the lock prompt)

   ```
   gconftool --set --type=bool /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled False
   gconftool --unset /apps/gnome-screensaver/themes
   ```
4. failed: To make it permanent:

sudo service gdm stop
sudo X -configure
vim /home/[username]/xorg.conf.new

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    DPMS       "false"  <<<<<<<<< Added this line
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

I tried the following suggested command from the [Ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1310646) but the whole system froze:

```
sudo pm-suspend
```

**Follow up:**
https://askubuntu.com/questions/37761/xorg-conf-in-ubuntu-natty-11-04

http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml

Comment: Dumb question, but can you confirm that you don't want the simple GUI answer, or that they don't work for some reason?

Comment: @Dennis: not with GUI.

Comment: Once again, no help but... did you also post on http://askubuntu.com/ the stack exchange site dedicated to Ubuntu? For example this one approaches what you are asking http://askubuntu.com/questions/27435/how-can-i-change-or-shut-off-a-screensaver-setting-without-using-gnome

Comment: @Dennis: I tried that example, still not working what i am trying. But after waiting 5 / 6 minutes as idle, it still turn off my monitor. And when i press enter it (does not show now lock prompt).

Comment: I want system do not turn of my monitor, nor it put that lock screen, nor screen saver, nothing. Just leave it as it is when you are working. How can i do that?

Comment: If i am idle for longer, it turns of my monitor, black, i do not want that, i want to disable that. Any idea how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting the screensaver turned off I found that it was the power manager that kept putting the screen to sleep.  For me the following worked `xset -dpms` which I found at http://v2kblog.blogspot.com/2008/08/disabling-monitor-power-saver.html and it included steps to set it up permanently.

Comment: Thanks. In the terminal/or via ssh i can do this to play with and works. e.g: 1. Turn off: export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xset dpms force off  2. Turn on: export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xset -dpms.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the lock seemed to work for me on Ubuntu 14.04

```
DISPLAY=:0 sudo gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
```

Comment: where/when do you add that line to enable it?